# How to concatenate multiple variables

Tags: raspbian, python

I have three UV sensors - integers output; one BMW280 - float output (temperature and pressure); and one GPS Module - float output.
I need to build a string in this form - **#teamname;temperature;pressure;uv_1;uv_2;uv_3;gpscoordinates#**

and send them via ser.write at least one time per second- I'm using APC220 Module
What is the fastest way to do this?

Now I'm only send temperature:

```py
ser.write(('Temperature: %0.2f \n'%(temp)).encode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks.

E.

### EDIT

Ok, is this making any sense?

```
textstr = str("#" + "teamname" + ";" + str(temperature) + ";" + str(pressure) + ";" + str(uv_1) + ";" + str(uv_2) + ";" + str(uv_3) + "#")

(...)

ser.write(('%s \n'%(textstr)).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site. It's easy to join - just click the "hamburger patties" at the top right of the browser area, scroll until you find stack overflow (or enter in the search box), click on it, and then click the "join community" button. Alternatively, try the docs for [pySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

Comment: Thank you!
BTW what is the difference between these two sites?

Comment: This site (RPi) is for... Raspberry Pi :)   StackOverflow is for programming-related questions mostly. There's overlap (and you may get a great answer to your programming questions here on RPi), but your question seems "independent" of RPi; by that I only mean that the answer is independent of your target platform.

Comment: Ah, ok! As I'm working with RPi I decided to ask here... 
(I will have to wait 90min to ask also on StackOverflow)

Thank you

Comment: 90 minute wait?! I did not know that!